# Does inequality signs matter when we evaluate a runtime?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The difference between foo1 and foo2 is the equality signs in the for loop. When we're evaluating runtime how does the inequality affect our output?

```
int foo1(int n)
{
   int i, j, x = 0;

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)

        x++;

    return x;
}

int foo2(int n)
{
   int i, j, x = 0;

   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j < n; j++)

        x++;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)` is the same as `for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)`. Does that help? It should only change e.g. O(n) to O(n+1) or O(n²) to O(n²+n).

Comment: Do you just mean "does it matter in this specific case" or also "in general does it ever matter"?

Comment: So in this case foo1 would be O(n^2) and foo2 would be O(constant * n^2)? @tobias_k

Comment: @harold in this specific case.

Comment: @Neo No, `<` would stop sooner than `<=`, thus a lower bound. Also, it's not a constant factor but more like a "linear additive" (not sure if that's the right term). I'd say `foo1` is O(n²) and `foo2` is O((n-1)²) = O(n²-2n+1), as both loops do n and (n-1) iterations, respectively. But in terms of complexity, both are O(n²) and thus the same.

Answer (score 3):

The loops with the `<=` can be re-written to loops with just `<` and vice versa.

```
int foo1(int n)
{
   int i, j, x = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        x++;
    return x;
}

int foo2(int n)
{
   int i, j, x = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= (n-1); i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= (n-1); j++)
        x++;
    return x;
}
```

Now we can see, that the loops in `foo1` both loop `n` times, giving `foo1` O(n²), whereas the loops in `foo2` both loop `(n-1)` times, giving `foo2` O((n-1)²) = O(n²-2n+1), which also is reflected in the returned values for `x`.

In terms of overall complexity, though, both functions are considered O(n²), thus whether you use `<` or `<=` does not really matter, at least in loops like the ones you've shown.